How to pass a Junit Test for a Primefaces FileUploadEvent
i have a doubt about how to pass a JUnit test for a Primefaces FileUploadEvent.
The methods is this:
public void cambiarLogoCrear(FileUploadEvent event) {
    cambiarLogo(event, false);
}
    
private void cambiarLogo(FileUploadEvent event, boolean modificando) {
    UploadedFile nuevoLogo = event.getFile();
    
    String nombre = nuevoLogo.getFileName();
        
    if(!nombre.endsWith(".png") && !nombre.endsWith(".jpeg") && !nombre.endsWith(".jpg")) {
        FacesMessagesUtils.mostrarMensajeDelProperties("empresa.accion.subirlogo.FICHERO_NO_IMAGEN", COMUN_ERROR_MESSAGE, FacesMessage.SEVERITY_WARN);
    }else {
        String carpeta = fachada.obtenerRutaParaImagenesDeClase(ClasesRutasEnum.EMPRESA);
        if(carpeta != null) {
            carpeta = carpeta + "temp" + File.separator;
            String nombreArchivo = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
            
            if(modificando) {
                FileSystemUtils.borrarFichero(this.empresaEnUso.getLogo());
            }
                
            String rutaLogo = FileSystemUtils.intentarSubirImagen(nombreArchivo, nuevoLogo, carpeta);
            this.empresaEnUso.setLogo(rutaLogo);
        }else {
            FacesMessagesUtils.mostrarMensajeDelProperties("empresa.accion.subirlogo.ERROR_CARPETA_IMAGENES_EMPRESAS", COMUN_ERROR_MESSAGE,
                        FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR);
            logger.error("Error al obtener la carpeta de imagenes temporales para empresas");
        }
            
    }   
}

In the test case i try to use a fake FileUploadEvent with this code
UploadedFile uploadedFileNormal = new UploadedFile() {
            
        @Override
        public void write(String filePath) throws Exception {
            // Do nothing
        }
            
        @Override
        public long getSize() {
            return 0;
        }
        
        @Override
        public InputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
            return new FileInputStream(file);
        }
        
        @Override
        public String getFileName() {
            return "defaultUser.png";
        }
        
        @Override
        public String getContentType() {
            return "application/octet-stream";
        }
        
        @Override
        public byte[] getContent() {
            try {
                return Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath());
            }catch (Exception e) {
                return null;
            }
        }
            
        @Override
        public void delete() throws IOException {
            // Do nothing
        }
};

FileUploadEvent event = new FileUploadEvent(null, uploadedFileNormal);

but this return a java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/el/ELException
then i try to create a FileUpload component to pass de FileUploadEvent:
FileUpload input = new FileUpload();
                
FileUploadEvent event = new FileUploadEvent(input, uploadedFileNormal);

but returns the same error: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/el/ELException
How can I realize what I want?
Versions of Software:

Java 8
Primefaces 11
JUnit 5.9

Many Thanks
